# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting an error when I try to access log in page in MVC web application. Things which I was done:

1. Re-Install Visual Studio 2017
2. Re-Install Entity Framework
3. Create new projects on all directories for testing.
4. Add references of system.data.entity

The error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570)

Answer (score 0):

First clear your ASP.NET Temporary files located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.
Then launch Visual Studio as an administrator and try compiling your solution.